# awk: split a column of delimited text in a row into lines

Tags: awk

I have a file with five columns and the second column has delimited text. I want to split that delimited text dedup it and print into lines. I'm able to do it with the commands below. I want to make a awk script. Can anyone help me.

```
awk -F"\t" 'NR>1{print $2}' <input file> | awk -F\| '{for (i = 0; ++i <= NF;) print $i}' | awk '!x[$0]++'
```

Input file:

```
test    hello|good|this|will|be    23421    test    4543
test2    good|would|may|can    43234    test2    3421
```

Output:

```
hello
good
this
will
be
would
may
can
```

Comment: So what would the desired output be? Please [edit] your question to show us.

Comment: @TomFenech Thanks for looking into this. I have made the edits.

Comment: So it's important to retain the order?

Comment: Should duplicate word be printed or not?

Comment: do it in bash. `awk '{print $2}' inputfile|sed 's/|/\n/gp'|sort|uniq`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote exactly Tom's answer before I saw it. If you want to maintain the order of the words as they are seen, it's a little more work:

```
awk '
    {
        n = split($2, a, "|")
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++) 
            if (!(a[i] in seen)) {
                # the hash to store the unique keys
                seen[a[i]] = 1
                # the array to store the keys in order
                words[++count] = a[i]
            }
    }
    END {for (i=1; i<=count; i++) print words[i]}
' file
```

```
hello
good
this
will
be
would
may
can
```

Comment: No need for the `END` block, you can just print the elements as they appear (see my edit).

Answer (score 2):

You could use this single awk one-liner:

```
$ awk '{split($2,a,"|");for(i in a)if(!seen[a[i]]++)print a[i]}' file
will
be
hello
good
this
can
would
may
```

The second field is split into the array `a` on the `|` character. Each element of `a` is printed if it isn't already in `seen`, which will only be true on the first occurrence.

Note that the order of the keys is undefined.

---

To preserve the order, you can use this:

```
$ awk '{n=split($2,a,"|");for(i=1;i<=n;++i)if(!seen[a[i]]++)print a[i]}' file
```

`split` returns the number of elements in the array `a`, which you can use to loop through them in the order they appeared.

Comment: See my post on how to prevent order of data from being changed.

Comment: @Jotne your version prints duplicate elements, which doesn't match the OP's desired output. See my edit for a way that preserves the order without printing duplicates.

Comment: Op may just have forget the last `good`.  I do not see anything mention not printing duplicates.

Comment: @Jotne there *is* the word "good" in the output, only the first time though. My second example reproduces the output in the question. Note that the question mentions "dedup"ing as well, i.e. removing duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would have done it:

```
awk '{n=split($2,a,"|");for (i=1;i<=n;i++) print a[i]}' file
hello
good
this
will
be
good
would
may
can
```

---

Or this way (this may change the order of the outdata, but for some reason I am not sure about, it works fine here):

```
awk '{split($2,a,"|");for(i in a) print a[i]}' file
hello
good
this
will
be
good
would
may
can
```

---

Or if you do not like duplicate output:

```
awk '{split($2,a,"|");for(i in a) if (!f[a[i]]++) print a[i]}' file
hello
good
this
will
be
would
may
can
```